# Increasing the size of deliverable diamond in PlantUML gantt chart?

Tags: gantt-chart, plantuml

The following plantuml file: `gantt.uml` creates a gantt chart with increased thickness of the bars and an increased font, such that it is better legible if there are many items in the Gantt chart.

```
@startgantt
project starts the 2021/07-22
saturday are closed
sunday are closed
skinparam classFontSize 100


[<size:30>Document relevant studies - 0.2] as [0_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Deliverable: Literature Study - 0.3] as [0_3] happens at [0_2]'s end
[<size:30>Overlapping Research Project - 1] as [1] lasts 11 days

[0_3] happens at [0_2]'s end
[1] starts at [0_2]'s end

[0_2]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1]  is colored in Cyan
@endgantt
```

Yielding:
[image]

However, I've noticed the size of the black diamond that resembles a deliverable does not grow along. Hence, I would like to ask:

*How can I increase the size of the black diamond that resembles a deliverable in the PlantUML gantt chart?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gantt charts now have lots of [style options](https://forum.plantuml.net/7255/enable-skinparam-for-gantt-charts?show=12004#a12004).

```
@startgantt
project starts the 2021/07-22
saturday are closed
sunday are closed

<style>
ganttDiagram {
    task {
        FontName Helvetica
        FontColor red
        FontSize 18
        FontStyle bold
        BackGroundColor blue
        LineColor yellow
    }
    milestone {
        FontColor blue
        FontSize 40
        FontStyle italic
        BackGroundColor yellow
        LineColor red
    }
}
</style>

[<size:30>Document relevant studies - 0.2] as [0_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Deliverable: Literature Study - 0.3] as [0_3] happens at [0_2]'s end
[<size:30>Overlapping Research Project - 1] as [1] lasts 11 days

[0_3] happens at [0_2]'s end
[1] starts at [0_2]'s end

[0_2]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1]  is colored in Cyan
@endgantt
```

[image]